# Select two elements from a list with specified colors for left and right element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help. This is the end result that I want. The user can select only two out of many elements. The element to the left is always green and the element to the right is alway blue, only two elements are selectable at a time.

[image: Preview]

I do know the overall flow:

1. Get the nearest element with an active class
2. Remove the active class
3. Set the active class to the currently clicked element
4. Reset colors.

But the code I have right now is failing. Will you please take a look and point out my coming short? (I think the .nearest() function may be the problem)

```js
$.fn.nearest = function(selector) {
  // base case if we can't find anything
  if (this.length == 0)
    return this;
  var nearestSibling = this.prevAll(selector + ':first');
  if (nearestSibling.length > 0)
    return nearestSibling;
  return this.parent().nearest(selector);
};
jQuery(document).on('click', '.page-list-item.is-tiny', function() {
  $(this).parent().nearest(".active").removeClass("active a-active b-active");
  $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  var selectedElements = $('.ab-pages > .active');
  var first = $(selectedElements[0]);
  var second = $(selectedElements[1]);
  first.removeClass("a-active b-active").addClass("a-active");
  second.removeClass("a-active b-active").addClass("b-active");
});
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

span {
  font-style: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}

.title {
  word-break: break-word;
}

.title span {
  font-weight: inherit;
}

.title {
  color: #363636;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.125;
}

.column {
  display: block;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  padding: 0.75rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .column.is-one-fifth {
    flex: none;
    width: 20%;
  }
}

.columns {
  margin-left: -0.75rem;
  margin-right: -0.75rem;
  margin-top: -0.75rem;
}

.columns:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: calc(1.5rem - 0.75rem);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .columns:not(.is-desktop) {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.center {
  text-align: center !important;
}

.padding-top-1 {
  padding-top: 10px !important;
}

.padding-bottom-1 {
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.page-list-item {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-list-item:hover {
  border-color: #22B66E;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.page-list-item-body .title {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #606F81;
}

.page-list-item.is-tiny {
  max-width: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: none;
}

.active:nth-of-type(1) .page-list-item,
.a-active .page-list-item {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #22B66E !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #22B66E !important;
}

.b-active .page-list-item {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #53A6FA !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #53A6FA !important;
}

.ab-pages {
  padding: 30px;
}

.ab-pages .page-list-item {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columns ab-pages is-mobile">
  <div class="column is-one-fifth active a-active">
    <div id="1" class="page-list-item is-tiny">
      <div><img src=""></div>
      <div class="page-list-item-body center">
        <p class="title padding-top-1 padding-bottom-1"><span>Nicename</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column is-one-fifth">
    <div id="2" class="page-list-item is-tiny">
      <div><img src=""></div>
      <div class="page-list-item-body center">
        <p class="title padding-top-1 padding-bottom-1"><span>Nicename....</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column is-one-fifth active b-active">
    <div id="3" class="page-list-item is-tiny">
      <div><img src=""></div>
      <div class="page-list-item-body center">
        <p class="title padding-top-1 padding-bottom-1"><span>New page</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column is-one-fifth">
    <div id="4" class="page-list-item is-tiny">
      <div><img src=""></div>
      <div class="page-list-item-body center">
        <p class="title padding-top-1 padding-bottom-1"><span>New page 4</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column is-one-fifth">
    <div id="5" class="page-list-item is-tiny">
      <div><img src=""></div>
      <div class="page-list-item-body center">
        <p class="title padding-top-1 padding-bottom-1"><span>New page 5</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not use an array with the latest clicked items and take only the last two for changing the color and short the length of the array by keeping the last two?

Comment: Dies scheint wirklich eine schlauere Alternative zu sein!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I attempted to do that with .active:first-of-type and .active:last-of-type but it wouldn't work.

Comment: Your MCVE must be **self-contained**. Please copy the necessary styles from your external stylesheet into the snippet.

Comment: @JonRiel: English only on SO (yes, even though Nina speaks German -- not every one else does).

Answer (score 0):

I shall now proceed with the answer of my own question in tune of the users' comments above.

```js
// Get the closest number element of an array
function closest(array, num) {
  var i = 0;
  var minDiff = 1000;
  var ans;
  for (i in array) {
    var m = Math.abs(num - array[i]);
    if (m < minDiff) {
      minDiff = m;
      ans = array[i];
    }
  }
  return ans;
}

// Removes active classes and adds them afresh
function updateSelection() {
  $(".ab-pages > .active").removeClass("active a-active b-active");
  $("#" + selected[0]).parent().addClass("active a-active");
  $("#" + selected[1]).parent().addClass("active b-active");
}

// For sorting an array by number value
function sortNumber(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

// Initialise with the array values 1, 4
var selected = [1, 4];

jQuery(document).on('click', '.page-list-item.is-tiny', function() {
// Numerical value representing an Element
  var id = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
  // Closest matching number in Array
  var cl = closest(selected, id);
  // Remove closest item from Array
  var index = selected.indexOf(cl);
  if (index > -1) {
    selected.splice(index, 1);
  }
  // Append this clicked Element
  selected.push(id);
  // Sort the selected array by num ASC
  selected = selected.sort(sortNumber);
  // Reset the index of the array so that selected[0] and selected[1] are well defined
  selected = selected.filter(function() {
    return true;
  });
  // Add active classes afresh
  updateSelection();
});
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

span {
  font-style: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}

.title {
  word-break: break-word;
}

.title span {
  font-weight: inherit;
}

.title {
  color: #363636;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.125;
}

.column {
  display: block;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  padding: 0.75rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .column.is-one-fifth {
    flex: none;
    width: 20%;
  }
}

.columns {
  margin-left: -0.75rem;
  margin-right: -0.75rem;
  margin-top: -0.75rem;
}

.columns:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: calc(1.5rem - 0.75rem);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .columns:not(.is-desktop) {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.center {
  text-align: center !important;
}

.padding-top-1 {
  padding-top: 10px !important;
}

.padding-bottom-1 {
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.page-list-item {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-list-item:hover {
  border-color: #22B66E;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.page-list-item-body .title {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #606F81;
}

.page-list-item.is-tiny {
  max-width: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: none;
}

.a-active .page-list-item {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #22B66E !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #22B66E !important;
}

.b-active .page-list-item {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #53A6FA !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #53A6FA !important;
}

.ab-pages {
  padding: 30px;
}

.ab-pages .page-list-item {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columns ab-pages is-mobile">
  <div class="column is-one-fifth active a-active">
    <div id="1" class="page-list-item is-tiny">
      <div><img src=""></div>
      <div class="page-list-item-body center">
        <p class="title padding-top-1 padding-bottom-1"><span>Nicename</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column is-one-fifth">
    <div id="2" class="page-list-item is-tiny">
      <div><img src=""></div>
      <div class="page-list-item-body center">
        <p class="title padding-top-1 padding-bottom-1"><span>Nicename....</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column is-one-fifth active b-active">
    <div id="3" class="page-list-item is-tiny">
      <div><img src=""></div>
      <div class="page-list-item-body center">
        <p class="title padding-top-1 padding-bottom-1"><span>New page</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column is-one-fifth">
    <div id="4" class="page-list-item is-tiny">
      <div><img src=""></div>
      <div class="page-list-item-body center">
        <p class="title padding-top-1 padding-bottom-1"><span>New page 4</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column is-one-fifth">
    <div id="5" class="page-list-item is-tiny">
      <div><img src=""></div>
      <div class="page-list-item-body center">
        <p class="title padding-top-1 padding-bottom-1"><span>New page 5</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```